# Trying to map Enum and Structs with serde yaml

Tags: rust

I am trying to read from a yaml file with serde, however it keeps giving me the error *Error("invalid type: map, expected a YAML tag starting with '!'", line: 2, column: 1)*
even though I definitely am using a !. I am using a similar structure to a previous program I made, and in the previous version it works fine. Here I am using a mix of Enum and Struct and in the previous one just Enum so maybe that's the problem.

The code I have so far is as followed:

```
#[derive(Debug,Deserialize)]
enum Blocdef {
    ConfigLink(String,Inputdeck),
}
#[derive(Debug,Deserialize)]
struct Inputdeck {
    config: HashMap<String,u64>,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), serde_yaml::Error> {
    let s = "
- !ConfigLink['NameTest', Inputdeck:{config: {'00': 63,'01': 56}}]
";
    let deck: Result<Blocdef, serde_yaml::Error> = serde_yaml::from_str(&s);
    println!("{:?}",deck);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: If you generate a Blockdec and serailize it, it returns `---\nConfigLink:\n  - NameTest\n  - config: {}\n`, so itI am not sure your representation works.

Comment: In YAML `-` means you're starting a sequence, i.e. it'll try to parse this into a Rust `Vec`. If you fix your YAML to look like `"!ConfigLink ['NameTest', config: {'00': 63,'01': 56}]"` and are on `serde_yaml` version 0.9, it works.